# Aria2 don't re-download file

Tags: aria2

I'm using aria2 to download a list of files that is dynamically generated. I want it to skip the files that are already in the download directory, but instead of doing this, it just re-downloads them and adds a `.1` to the filename. I tried using `--check-integrity=true`, but that did not change the behavior. Is there a way to make it skip files that already exist?

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to superuser?

Comment: I suppose it could, but there are even fewer aria2 questions on superuser than there are on SO.

Comment: BTW, use the `--continue[=true]` option to resume downloads.

Comment: @ShmuelH. That is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: Has using `--continue=true` resolved your problem? If yes, I suggest @Shmuel to post it as the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding `--continue=true` to your command.

According to the `aria2c(1)` man-page, `-c, --continue[=true|false]`:

> Continue  downloading  a partially downloaded file.  Use this option to resume a download started by a web browser or another program which downloads files sequentially from the beginning.   Currently this option is only applicable to HTTP(S)/FTP downloads.

Comment: Does this have the potential of downloading the whole site all over again? How does it figure out if a download is partial or full? Wouldn't it have to compare with the remote version?

Comment: I believe that the --continue option is dangerous and can produce invalid files in OP's case. Imagine the first run downloads some files (e.g. dynamic JSON documents). Then --continue will "resume" those downloads - if server has generated a longer document, then aria2c will happily "resume" that file, corrupting it in the process.

Answer (score 26):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/865#issuecomment-292594721) the way to go should be

```
--auto-file-renaming=false
```

> If a control file (.aria2) exists then the download will resume,
>   otherwise if no control file exists then since --allow-overwrite is
>   false by default the file will not be re-downloaded.