# Aria2 continue download

Tags: bash, debian, aria2

I have an alias for aria2 that downloads from an input file from an ftp server. This is how I had it setup.

```
aria2c --max-concurrent-downloads=1 --max-connection-per-server=6 --ftp-user=<user> --ftp-passwd=<password> --dir=/home/<username>/Downloads --input-file=/home/<username>/scripts/downloads.txt
```

I ran into an issue just now, not sure why as it never happened before, where it wouldn't continue and would try to re-download the files as .1.

So I read the man page and saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815994/7035457) I see there is  **--continue**, so I just changed it to

```
aria2c --max-concurrent-downloads=1 --max-connection-per-server=6 --continue=true --ftp-user=<user> --ftp-passwd=<password> --dir=/home/<username>/Downloads --input-file=/home/<username>/scripts/downloads.txt
```

So it works now, but my only issue is that it has to loop through the input file and check each download, making sure they're downloaded, until it finds where it left off. So for only 4 files downloaded out of 10 (all are under 1gb) it started at 15:51:52 and only found the aria2 file(#5/10) to resume at 16:00:16. Sometimes I'm dealing with 20+ files, or files larger than 1gb, and I'm unsure if that'll also change for the download size itself. This could make a large delay of like an hour potentially. Is there anyway to force it to search for an existing aria2 file in the directory and immediately start there, or do I just have to deal with it or remove finished files from the text file to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

`aria2c` always uses its state `.aria2` file if present. However, it's removed as soon as file is downloaded completely.

You ask it to download only *1 file at a time*. It needs some time to check the current file is downloaded completely.

Try adding [`--force-save=true`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-force-save) to preserve the session file even when download is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have 15,000 files and ended up writing a wrapper around aria2c that checks first if a file is already there and that the file size is the same and skips files like this. It may be that aria2c is the wrong tool for this job. Have you had a look at lftp and it's "mirror" command?